# Querying for array in embedded list

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Supposed I have a mongo document that looks similar to the following:

```
{
   'foo':1
   'listOfLists' : [ [1,2],[3,4] ]
}
```

(Yes I am aware this isn't how it "really" looks but it should be simple enough for explanation purposes.)

If I wanted to write a query that would check to see if the listsOfLists list object contains the combination of [3,4], how could I go about doing that?

Could I do something like

```
collection.find({'listsOfLists' : {'$elemMatch' : [3,4] } })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
collection.find({ 'listsOfLists': [3,4] }).
```

It's just a "direct match" on the property. MongoDB will look at each array element automatically. You don't need [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here.

If you were to use it, you need an operator expression, such as [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/):

```js
collection.find({ 'listsOfLists': { '$elemMatch': { '$eq': [3,4] } } }).
```

But that of course is not required unless there are "two or more" conditions that actually need to match on the array elements. Which is what [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is actually for.

Comment: So, in a related item. Could I use $elemMatch to check to see if just the First element in a list matches a query? Something like { '$elemMatch' : { '$eq' : 3} }

Comment: @K.Niemczyk That would actually be [Another Question to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but it is one with a logical answer. Post another question here if you cannot work it out.