# Pymongo: Querying specific list elements within a Mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I asked a previous question related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439892/querying-for-array-in-embedded-list/36439936#36439936) but let's say I have a document that looks like the following:

```
{
   'foo':1
   'listOfLists' : [ [1,2],[3,4],.... ]
}
```

How could I got about querying to see if the first element of an entry in the listOfLists field matches a certain value? From my previous question

```
collection.find({'listOfLists' : {'$elemMatch' : {'$eq': [3,4] } } })
```

would match the document, but what if I only wanted to check if the first element was a 3? The previous question did inform me that for direct matches, I don't need to use `$elemMatch` but could I do just the first element check using it? Perhaps something like

```
collection.find({'listOfLists' : {'$elemMatch' : 3 } })
```

This shouldn't work, I would think, because it would be trying to compare a list to an integer at that point. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you can do the following:

```
collection.find({'listOfLists': {'$elemMatch': {'0': {"$eq": 3}}}})
```

In this case the `{"$eq": 3}` part would only be applied to the first elements of the `listOfLists` inner sublists.